# concatenate array in julia

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation, julia

How can I concatenate two-dimensional arrays in Julia?

They are of type `Array{UInt8, 2}`.

I have tried `hvcat()`, but I get the error message

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching hvcat(::Array{UInt8,2}, ::Array{UInt8,2})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How exactly do you want to concatenate them?  The following, for example, both work:

```
A = rand(UInt8, 2,2)
B = rand(UInt8, 2,2)

C = [A B]
D = [A ; B]
```

Answer (score 2):

Two 2-D arrays of type `UInt8` can be concatenated like this:

```
C = cat(1, array1, array2)
```